# Does running a laptop without the battery cause it to consume more power?

Tags: laptop, battery, power

If I am using a laptop without battery and running it on direct charging, does it consume more power or same as with battery?

Comment: As an aside, it should help the life of the battery!

Comment: If the battery is charged, the same amount, however batteries also serve to absorb voltage/current spikes that can occur while charging, which is also why you shouldn't remove a battery from a running car or start a car without a battery installed, as while the battery's main purpose is to provide enough current to turn the starter, it's secondary purpose is to absorb any voltage/current spikes from the alternator.

Comment: It completely depends on the laptop make and model and how the manufacturer of the laptop has configured the laptop to behave in different power consumption and usage situation.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops come with default settings that optimize laptop power consumption in battery mode for longest possible battery life. This means that actually *yes* your laptop will consume less power (in total) when running on the battery if correct settings are applied. However energy saving settings are always a trade off between power consumption/ battery life and performance. To save power laptops decrease clocking frequency of processor, GPU, brightness of the screen and god knows what else.

There are few things to consider:

- Different laptop manufacturers have different default power saving options, so you can never be sure unless you have actually checked your settings
- You will have to charge laptop once in a while and Energy conversion efficiency off charging circuit is by any means not 100%, so there will be some power loss when charging laptop
- Overall machine performance will often degrade when running of battery

*You should be more specific when asking a question*

If your aim is to save energy (for whatever reason), then keep using the laptop in a way that is most convenient to (I mean with battery or without it), and try to adjust power saving settings in your OS. This will give you the optimal result.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it would consume **either more or less power over time** compared to running on battery.

By removing the main battery from the laptop, there will be no need (or ability) to recharge the battery. That will save some amount of power. You can calculate approximately how much by taking the battery capacity, dividing it by the charge time from empty to full, and add a reasonable margin.

However, many laptops are set up to run things in a more power-hungry mode when on mains power. That is mainly done to conserve battery power when mains power is not available. So when running on battery, the laptop might step down the frequency of the CPU, lower the screen brightness, and so on. If it runs at full tilt, that will make it consume more power.

If you set your laptop to run in a power-saving mode even when running on mains, and remove the battery, the laptop *should* draw less power than with the battery installed. However, it would probably come pretty close to that by just running the laptop in the same power-saving mode with the battery installed but also hooked up to mains power.